# Prediction with glmnet for ridge regression

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction

I used the cross validation function from the glmnet package to get my optimal lambda. Now I want use the model with the optimal lambda to compute the mse of the test data set. For that i need the predicted values of the test data set.

Should i first use the glmnet function to estimate the train data with the optimal lambda that i get via cross validation and store this model and use it for the prediction of the test data values?
Like this:

```
 fitOptRidge5 <- glmnet(x[train ,], y[train], alpha = 0,standardize=TRUE, lambda = cvRidge5$lambda.min)
```

and predict like this :

```
 ridgePred5 <- predict (fitOptRidge5 ,s=cvRidge5$lambda.min
  ,newx=x[test ,])
```

I am not sure about my approach because i set 2 times the optimal lambda.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on the Data Science SE or [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I agree with @Hack-R this sounds like a statistical question.  But we should check before migrating it; I don't understand the last sentence "because I set 2 times the optimal lambda".  What does that mean because it doesn't look like you are from the code you've given?  What exactly are you asking when you say "should I" (On Cross-Validated they will certainly ask you what your purpose of the modelling is before anyone can answer a should question)?  Why are you unsure?